# print something and result is null

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the code and when I run code it's print my result correctly but there is a null as result (in line 4) :

```
  main() {
      var ferrari = Car();
      ferrari.armor = 85;
      print(ferrari.armor);
  }
  class Car {
      int? _armor;

  int? get armor {
      return _armor;
  }
  set armor(int? armor) {
      if (armor != null && armor < 100) {
      print(true);
   }  else {
      print(false);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a variable that you give to it a custom `getter` and `setter`, so basically when you call the getter `ferrari.armor` it returns the `_armor` from your class, but since you see the `_armor` in your code will be always `null` because actaully you didn't give it any value in the `setter`, so it stays always null.
here propably what you wanted to do.

```
    main() {
  var ferrari = Car();
  ferrari.armor = 85;
  print(ferrari.armor);
}

class Car {
  int? _armor;

  int? get armor {
    return _armor;
  }

  set armor(int? armor) {

    if (armor != null && armor < 100) {
    _armor = armor; // add this

      print(true);
    } else {
      print(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the set function, you need to set the `_armor.`

```
set armor(int? armor) {
  if (armor != null && armor < 100) {
    _armor = armor; // Set _armor to armor here.
    print(true);
  } else {
    print(false);
  }
}
```